# What is the most proper js library for “tree-like” chart

Tags: javascript, data-visualization, charts

What is the most proper JS library to arrange objects across one Y-axis assuming that Y-axis is a sequence (date or int)?
Similar to attached image.
[image: tree]

I've spent a lot of time to find proper js library ([TimelineJS](http://timeline.knightlab.com/), [csslab](http://www.csslab.cl/2011/08/18/jquery-timelinr/), TimegliderJS, Tiki-Toki, Highcharts, Jscharts, Google), but noone has similar to one vertical axis.
Any ideas how to organize arrangement of the sequence objects?

Comment: Thanks, Betty. Thew last one is almost what I need.